# Replacing Ceiling Fan with Light Fixture - No Wall Switch

Tags: electrical

I would like to replace my ceiling fan with a standard light fixture, however, there is not a wall switch.  What are my options if I do not want to install a wall switch?

Comment: Was it just a fan or was there a light, too? How did you turn the fan (and light) on?

Comment: It was a fan/light combo with pull chains.

Comment: Please take the [tour] - you'll see that the proper way to say "thank you" is to click the up vote arrow next to answers you find useful. In a day or so, click the check-mark next to the answer you found _most_ helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You've got many choices. There are pull chain fixtures, Smart fixtures, Smart bulbs for a regular fixture or standard fixtures with a remote control similar to the one pictured below from Amazon

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I installed a switch similar to [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S2RM95K) for a client.
It is receiver with a remote switch, it works quite well and solves your problem with ease.

You wire in the little receiver unit to the fixture inside the electrical box and you can put the wireless remote switch any place you like.

You can get more then one switch for the same receiver or visa versa.